# "Famous for" or "famous of"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> City A is famous for\ of planting melons and watermelons in summer.

I noticed somewhere in internet that using for is 66% while other prepositions that can be used after the term famous such as ( about, of, in, at ) are the rest 34%

Is this true in English grammar? I feel as if something went wrong while I say for examples:

> He is famous for saying the truth.
>   He is famous for bravery.
>   He is famous for saying poetry.

I think using *famous of* gives the phrase or the sentence more stress than *famous for*. I dislike using *for* in such circumstances! What do you say?

Comment: Finding that the word famous can be followed, somehow, by 'of' does not offer much of a lesson. I've never seen it in print.  I will say that if a search for 'famous' shows many hits and 'faymuss' shows few, you would know which is spelled the right way, but that's a different comparison.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Which preposition or word to use after _famous_ depends on context and the meaning you are trying to convey.  You really don't show the results of your search.  "famous for" is standard; other prepositions offer other meanings.

Answer (score 5):

Which one is correct depends on what you want to say. They are not interchangeable. You can say:

> This restaurant is **famous for** its French cuisine.

Or:

> Michael is the most **famous of** the Jackson brothers.

Comment: Oh, touché Michael.

Answer (score 3):

Very often when somebody asks about which preposition to use here, it is actually a question about what a particular word (usually a verb or adjective) takes.

This is such a case. It happens to be the case that "famous" takes "for" and not "of": there is no reason for this, it just happens that way, and you need to learn it.

It is complete nonsense to talk about percentages of prepositions: this is not about "of" vs "for", this is about "famous for".